# Problem with Eclipse default equals() implementation

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa

I'm having some problems with the `equals` method generated by Eclipse.

Suppose I have an Entity Bean with the attributes `entityId` and `name`, but I just selected for the equals generation the `entityId` attribute. So, the code generated by eclipse is the following:

```
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Entity other = (Entity) obj;
        if (entityId == null) {
            if (other.entityId != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!entityId.equals(other.entityId))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

The problem is that when comparing two different instances of the class `Entity` that have `null` as the entityId, the `equals` method returns true.

For me, this `equals` implementation is not correct (at least when using it with JPA), because two entities without an `entityId` are just object that are going (probably) to be persisted as new objects in a database. If I add these two objects to a Set (one to many relationship, for example), after the two insertions the Set is going to have just one element (Sets don't allow duplicates).

So, the question is why Eclipse generates the equals method like this? Do you think is better to implement the `equals` method with the following code?

```
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Entity other = (Entity) obj;
        if (entityId == null) {
            if (other.entityId != null)
                return false;
            else 
                return true;
        } else if (!entityId.equals(other.entityId))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: from time to time, not all the fields are needed to figure decide equals. let's say you have two identical entities, erroneous added twice to the db. they'll have different id's. Does having a different id all of the sudden make it different entities?

Comment: But, let's say you have two objects with all their attributes (including the id) set as null. Could we say that they are the same object? I think no and thats why I asked this question

Comment: why would you allow to have instances for which all members are null?

Comment: I don't allow that, I am just saying that the equals implementation of Eclipse, in case of all attributes are null, is going to return true.

Comment: either you allow it, or you can't arrive in a situation where that can occur

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse simply doesn't know about how you will use your class.

Usually if fields have equal values objects considered equal

```
class Human {
    String name;
    String petName;
}
```

`Human("Bob", null)` is equal to `Human("Bob", null)`.

You case is somewhat special, so you have to made adjustment by yourself.

Comment: Suppose you have two Human(null, null) objects. Do they are equal? With the equal implementation of Eclipse they are the same, but can we really say that they are equal? I think no.

Comment: It can be both way. Depends on requirement. This is why declaring `equals` in `Object` was bad idea.

Comment: You are right, it can be both ways. I just want to know why Eclipse decide to go with true instead of false.

Comment: Because it is simplest semantic. Two objects are equal if all of their fields are equal.